# How to show that $h(x^p) \equiv h(x)^p \pmod{p}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why $g(x^{p})=(g(x))^{p}$ in the reduction mod $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172711/why-gxp-gxp-in-the-reduction-mod-p)

Let $h(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $p$ be a prime.
We know that for any integer $\alpha$ we have that $\alpha^p \equiv \alpha \pmod{p}$.
How can we use this to show that $h(x^p) \equiv h(x)^p \pmod{p}$? It seems to me that we have to reduce the indeterminate $x$ modulo $p,$ which does not make sense.

Comment: For $(h(x))^p$, imagine expanding using the Multinomial Theorem. All "mixed" multinomial coefficients are divisible by $p$.  Same as one of standard proofs of Fermat's Theorem.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas: I actually made a mistake: f and g need not have a factor in common. So i will retain only the first part of the question, which is already answered. If you could write it as an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: @Belgi I recalled seeing this question on M.SE before, but I wasn't able to search for it. I just figured out that search function is terrible with math.

Comment: @J.D. I think so to, I had it easy since it was my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine expanding 
$$\left(a_n x^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\cdots +a_0\right)^p$$
by using the Multinomial Theorem. All of the "mixed" multinomial coefficients are divisible by $p$, so modulo $p$ we end up with
$$a_n^p (x^n)^p +a_{n-1}^p(x^{n-1})^p +\cdots + a_0^p,$$
which, modulo $p$, is the same polymomial as
$$a_n(x^p)^n +a_{n-1}(x^p)^{n-1}+\cdots +a_0.$$

Answer (score 3):

By the binomial theorem,
$$
\begin{align}
(ax+by)^p
&=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k}(ax)^{p-k}(by)^k\\
&\equiv ax^p+by^p\pmod{p}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
because $\left.p\;\middle|\;\binom{p}{k}\right.$ except when $k=0$ or $k=p$, and because $a^p=a\pmod{p}$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Inductively using $(1)$, we get that 
$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\right)^p\equiv\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^{kp}\pmod{p}\tag{2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ By [Frobenius / Freshman's Dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream#Prime_characteristic) $\, z\to z^{p} $ is a ring hom,  so commute with polynomials, being compositions of  basic ring operations (which, by definition, hom's commute with).