# Prove that $\frac{\binom{p}{k}}{p}$ is integral for $k\in \{1,..,p-1\}$ with $p$ a prime number with a particular method

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisibility

I started by induction on $k$

For $k=1$ then : $1\in \mathbb{N}$

For $k=2$ then : $\frac{(p-1)}{2!} \in \mathbb{N}$ , indeed for all $p>{2}$, $p-1$ is even. (We still have $k<p$ it's important).

Suppose that $\frac{(p-1)...(p-k+1)}{k!} \in \mathbb{N}$ for a specific $k \in \{1,..,p-1\}$

Now try to prove that : $\frac{(p-1)...(p-k)}{(k+1)!} \in \mathbb{N}$.

By the recursive formula we have directly :

$\frac{\binom{p}{k+1}}{p} = \frac{[\binom{p+1}{k+1} - \binom{p}{k}]}{p}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\frac{(p-1)...(p-k)}{(k+1)!} = \frac{(p+1)(p-1)...(p-k+1)}{(k+1)!} - \frac{(p-1)...(p-k+1)}{k!}$

By hypothesis we know that $\frac{(p-1)...(p-k+1)}{k!} \in \mathbb{N}$

Now, the key is to see that a product of $k$ consecutive terms is divided by $k!$ (a little induction can solve this).

Then the induction is complete.

Comment: Hi. In the first line, when you use Pascal recursion, you should use $-$ instead of "+", does not it? If you do that, you will get $\frac{(p+1)-(k+1)}{k+1}=\frac{p-k}{k+1}$. Do not know if that is the right track.

Comment: Do you need to use induction? Otherwise there may be a direct proof that $\frac{{p \choose k}}{p}\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Phicar No you're right it is "-" but I still have the same problem for $k=1$.

Comment: @Kaladin There is a solution which consists to apply Gauss Lemma but I want to prove the result by induction.

Comment: You will have a lot of problems, not just for $1$. I suggest you to look further in $\frac{(p+1)(p-1)\ldots (p-k+1)}{(k+1)!}$.. you take out $p$, but $k+1<p$, so who will divide $p$?

Comment: I don't think $\frac{p-k}{k+1}\in\mathbb{N}$ take $k>\lfloor p/2\rfloor$ then $\frac{p-k}{k+1}<1$

Comment: @Phicar $p$ is a prime number so $1$ and $p$ can divide $p$

Comment: Do you need to use induction? Because if $\binom{p}{k}$ is an integer and $p$ divides $\binom{p}{k}$...

Comment: @AaronMaroja For me to prove that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{k}$ is not clear

Comment: @Maman  Well, $p$ is prime, and $\binom{p}{k}$ is an integer, suppose a factor of $k!$ divides $p$ , where is the contradiction?

Comment: Did you take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328655/proving-prime-p-divides-binompk-for-k-in-1-ldots-p-1)?

Comment: @AaronMaroja the fact is that $p$ is prime with every $k \in \{1,..,p-1\}$

Comment: That's right, then $p$ divides $\binom{p}{k}$.

Comment: @AaronMaroja I already knew this method but I just wanted to prove it by induction just to change the point of view (more formal)

Comment: I see, you could use valuation theory to do so, see the answer on the question I showed, really interesting approach.

Comment: @AaronMaroja maybe with my try we can prove that $\frac{(p+1)(p-1)\ldots (p-k+1)}{(k+1)!} \in \mathbb{N}$ but I don't see the right argument.

Comment: @AaronMaroja Is that true the fact $k!$ divide the product of $k$ numbers consecutively ?

Answer (score 2):

By definition,
$$\binom{p}{k} = \frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$$
Since $p$ is prime, it's relative prime to all smaller numbers, and therefore for $k<p$, it cannot be a factor of $k!$. Now if further $k>0$, then $p-k<p$, and thus $p$ is not a factor of $k!(n-k)!$. Since by definition, $p$ is a factor of $p!$, and $p$ is prime, it follows that it is a factor of $\binom{p}{k}$, thus $\binom{p}{k}/p\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: I think here should be reliance on to the fact $\binom{p}{k} \in \mathbb{N}$. However, +1.

Comment: It's right but as I said in the comments before I want to prove that $\frac{(p+1)(p-1)\ldots (p-k+1)}{(k+1)!}$ is an integer to complete the induction.