# If $0 < i < p$, then $p \mid \binom{p}{i}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

How do I prove this theorem?

For a prime number $p$ and integer $i$:

If $0 < i < p$ then $p \mid \binom{p}{i}$.

Comment: This was proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328655/proving-prime-p-divides-binompk-for-k-in-1-ldots-p-1

Comment: Since ${p \choose i} = \frac {p!}{(p-i)!i!}= p* \frac {(p-1)!}{(p-i)!i!} $and $p$ is prime, that should be pretty obvious, shouldn't it?

Comment: @fleablood That requires us to show that $\frac{(p-1)!}{(p-i)!i!}$ is an integer. Of course, it doesn't take more than a sentence or two, but I wouldn't say it's _obvious_.

Comment: @Arthur: Might be, might not be.  Yet another reason that it's useful when the OP states their level of understanding. :-)

Comment: We know ${a \choose b}$ is an integer. And we know that nothing less than $p$ has any factors in common with $p$.  No, it isn't obvious.  That was me being snide.  but looking at factors should be obvious first and seeing where to take it should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
The simplest proof uses the relation
$$\binom pk=\frac pk\binom{p-1}{k-1} \quad\text{for all}\; k>0 $$
and Gauss' lemma.