# For any prime number $p$ and natural number $i < p$, prove that $p$ divides ${p \choose i}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients, divisibility, prime-factorization

For any prime number $p$ and natural number $i < p$, prove that $p$ divides ${p \choose i}$.

Also, what happens when $p$ is not a prime. Is this still true?

I tried writing out the formula for combination but couldn't get further.

Comment: This question has been already asked before. I recommend you to search for the answers. On the other hand, if $ p $ isn't prime the statement is false. Just take for example $ p=6$ and $ i=3$.

Comment: [More generally](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242) $\,\displaystyle\dfrac{\gcd(n,m)}n{n\choose m}\, $ is an integer. OP is special case $\,n\,$ prime.

Comment: You should specify $0<i$, as “natural number” is far from unambiguously excluding $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true in general (look for a counterexample at $p=4$). For $p$ prime though, you have
$$
{p\choose i} = \frac{p!}{i!(p-i)!} \in \mathbb{N}
$$
So
$$
p \mid {p\choose i}i!(p-i)!
$$
However, $p\nmid i!, p\nmid (p-i)!$. So $p\mid {p\choose i}$.

Comment: You need to *justify* those indivisibilities - which are the crux of the matter.

Comment: So why does p not divide i! or (p - i)!  ?

Comment: If $k<p$, then $p\nmid j$ for each $1\leq j\leq k$. Since $p$ is prime, this implies $p\nmid k!$ as well (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma)

Answer (score 7):

By a combinatorial argument, or by manipulating factorials, we have
$$i\binom{p}{i}=p\binom{p-1}{i-1}\ .$$
Since $\binom{p-1}{i-1}$ is an integer,
$$p\mid i\binom{p}{i}\ .$$
But $p$ is prime and $1\le i<p$, so $p$ and $i$ have no common factor, so
$$p\mid \binom{p}{i}\ .$$
For the case when $p$ is not prime, just take $p=4$ and try out various values of $i$.

Comment: This method [generalizes to](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1165413/242) $\,\displaystyle\dfrac{\gcd(n,m)}n{n\choose m}\, $ is an integer. OP is special case $\,n\,$ prime.