# Prove that $q$ divides (${}_q \mathrm{C}_x$) where $q$ is an odd prime and $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ is such that $1\lt x \lt q$.

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

I believe I need to show that $\frac{q!}{x!(q-x)!} = aq $ where  $a\in \mathbb{Z}$
How can I show this?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving prime $p$ divides $\binom{p}{k}$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,p-1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328655/proving-prime-p-divides-binompk-for-k-in-1-ldots-p-1)

Answer (score 0):

There is the identity ${n \choose k } = {n \choose n-k}$, which means we may assume without loss of generality that $q - x \leq x$.  Then clearly the fraction is $\dfrac{q(q-1)\cdots (q-x+1)}{(q-x)(q-x-1) \cdots (1)}$.

Since $q$ is a prime number, you cannot write it as a multiple of two proper factors greater than $1$.  Notice that since $q-x \lt q$ (because by assumption $x \gt 1$), the only way to "divide out" the factor of $q$ in the numerator would be to assemble (compositely) $q$ from a number of smaller factors, but this can't be done by our first sentence in this paragraph.

$\square$